# How can the expression user-> { some code } be an Observer object?

Tags: java, android, lambda, observer-pattern, android-architecture-components

In the [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) by Google there is an example, which I do not understand -

**UserProfileViewModel:**

```
public class UserProfileViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private LiveData<User> user;
    public LiveData<User> getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

**UserProfileFragment:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    viewModel.getUser().observe(this, user -> {
      // Update UI.
    });
}
```

When I look at the [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData) reference, there is only the following `observe` method:

```
observe(LifecycleOwner owner, Observer<T> observer)
```

I am confused, that the method signature does not match:

The `LifecycleOwner` is the support library `Fragment`, all right.

But how can the expression `user-> { some code }` be an [Observer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Observer.html) object?

Comment: That is a Java 8 lambda expression, which the compiler will convert into an implementation of the `Observer` interface.

Comment: What does `user` mean then in that implementation of the interface?

Comment: That is a `User`. The lambda expression will be converted into an `Observer<User>`, since this is a `LiveData<User>`, and the `User` is passed into the `onChanged()` method formed from the body of the lambda expression.

Comment: Observer has a [single abstract method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23342499/3788176), and thus it can be instantiated with a lambda.

Comment: I still do not understand, why it is not `User -> { some code }` then...

Comment: @AlexanderFarber in fact it is, it is `User user -> { some code }`

Comment: Thanks, but `private User user;` is defined in `UserProfileViewModel` and not in `UserProfileFragment` where the `user -> { some code }` expression is used... so how does compiler know that `user` is a `User` instance?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber, The code is `viewModel.getUser().observe(this, user -> { ... })`.
The return type of `getUser()` is `LiveData<User> `. `getUser()` is public.

And, for clearance, `user -> { some code }` has nothing to do with the member `user` in terms of member name. It can be named anything, for example `u -> { ... }` would be pretty much the same. The type though, it's always `User` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `user-> { some code }` is a SAM (Single Abstract Method) type, more info in this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913409/what-is-a-sam-type-in-java).

In short it is just syntactic sugar for:

```
viewModel.getUser().observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable User user) {
        // Some code
    }
});
```