# How to override two and more methods of interface using Lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda

1.InterfaceOne is one interface having two methods ,my question i how to override that 2 methods using Lambda expression?

```
interface InOne{

    void m1();
    void m2();
}
public class LambdaExpForTwomethodsInInterface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //For One method overriding
        InOne one=()->{
            System.out.println("InOne m1");
        };
        one.m1();
    }
}
```

2.If there are 5 methods in interface,but i want to override only one method,is there any way to that using Lambda exp?

Comment: You *implement* methods from interface, don't *override*. Override is from class

Comment: Implimenting interface methods is called overriding right.That why mentioned the term @ Evgeni

Answer (score 4):

> is there any way to that using Lambda exp?

No, they are meant to be referencing only `FunctionalInterface`s.

> how to override that 2 methods using Lambda expression?

Though not possible using a lambda expression, you can still use an anonymous class to instantiate them:

```
InOne one = new InOne() {
    @Override
    public void m1() {

    }

    @Override
    public void m2() {

    }
};
```

Comment: You mean ,Lambda deal only with funtional interface?

Comment: @mae yup, precisely... Would refer you to read further details around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342499/why-functional-interfaces-in-java-8-have-one-abstract-method

Answer (score 0):

```
interface InOne {
    default void m1() {}
    default void m2() {}
}
```

#### Implement

```
InOne one = new InOne() {
    @Override
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("InOne m1");
    }
};

one.m1();  // InOue m1
one.m2();  // <nothing>
```

#### Implement using Lambda

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface InOneM1 {
    void m1();
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface InOneM2 {
    void m2();
}

InOneM1 oneM1 = () -> System.out.println("InOne m1");
InOneM2 oneM2 = () -> System.out.println("InOne m2");

oneM1.m1();
oneM2.m2();
```

Comment: If it is dealing only with Funtional interfaces ,then how it is dealing reducing code and giving much importance.I mean generally ,we have more then one methods in interfaces of  our  projects right..!

Comment: Right. Lambda works only with **Functional Interface**

Comment: @oleg.cherednik `<empty string>` rather shall mean `void`... by the way, there is another combination as well one of them being `default` and another being `abstract` to term the interface as `FunctionalInterface`... but that should be considered while approaching towards designing them.

Comment: @mae not every interface is supposed to be represented using lambdas.. you can still have interfaces which are not `FunctionalInterface`.. but in order to make use of them, one can design the interfaces and their hierarchy as such.