# How does a function from a functional interface perform a lambda function?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm trying to understand functional interfaces and lambda functions.And I can't find an explanation of how a function in a functional interface connects it with a lambda function , that is, let's say there is such a functional interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MyPredicate {
    boolean test(Integer value);
}
```

and now we assign the variables of the functional interface to the lambda function:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyPredicate myPredicate = x -> x > 0;
        System.out.println(myPredicate.test(10));   //true
    }
}
```

I'm exactly wondering why when calling `myPredicate.test(10)` a call is being made `x > 0`.
That is, do I understand correctly that when we assign a lambda function, the compiler somehow connects the function from the functional interface with the body of the lambda function?it's just that inheritance and override are usually used for this ,but here the compiler does it or how?I will be glad to have explanations to understand this issue

Comment: The functional interface has exactly one unimplemented method. The Lambda implements exactly one method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Functional Interfaces in Java 8 have one Abstract Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342499/why-functional-interfaces-in-java-8-have-one-abstract-method) Also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36882003/7804477) has a few other details as well.

Comment: @Turing85 but if lambda is a functional interface, then it can't have an implementation,isn't it?

Comment: The lambda expression is not a functional interface, it **implements** the functional interface.

Comment: *"but if lambda is a functional interface"* ... that's not what Turing85 wrote, they wrote "The Lambda **implements** exactly one method".

Comment: @Omegon `x > 0` would be the implementation. Assume you have class that implements `MyPredicate` that overrides the `test` with `return x > 0`, and then you create an object of this class and invoke `test(10)` for this object. Using a lambda `x -> x > 0` is equivalent to this, but avoids the need of explicitly creating an implementing class

Comment: @GauthamM okey,now it's more understandable, I just thought that there is an explanation of how this transformation (or binding) occurs.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly IS a lambda expression in pre-Java8 terms?

It's an instance of an anonymous class implementing the interface needed in the current context.

So, to understand

```
MyPredicate myPredicate = x -> x > 0;
```

we have to consider some different aspects.

Here, the lambda expression `x -> x > 0` is required to give a result compatible with `MyPredicate`. So, by considering the context where the expression is used, it is equivalent to

```
MyPredicate myPredicate = new MyPredicate() {
    boolean test(Integer whateverName) {
        // some method body
    }
};
```

Now, the lambda expression fills the body of that method. The `x ->` part defines the parameter name, so now we have

```
MyPredicate myPredicate = new MyPredicate() {
    boolean test(Integer x) {
        // some method body
    }
};
```

And the `x > 0` defines the body and the value to be returned:

```
MyPredicate myPredicate = new MyPredicate() {
    boolean test(Integer x) {
        return x > 0;
    }
};
```

So, when you call `myPredicate.test(10)`, there's nothing special going on. The (anonymous-class) instance in `myPredicate` gets its `test()` method called with argument `10`. It's only that this instance has been created using the lambda-expression syntax.